# jquery different selections from this click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, html-parsing

I have this code that doesn't really work

First I add a img div

```
$('div.group_title a').prepend("<img src='replace_w_img_link_in_real'  width='20' height='20'  >");
```

Then I make a selection of that div

```
$('.el.group_title a img').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var img2 = "img_link_path_2";
  var img1 = "img_link_path_1";

  var img = $(this).attr("src");

  if (img == img1) {
    $(this).attr("src",img2);
  } else {
    $(this).attr("src",img1);
  }

  $(this).nextUntil('.el.group_title', '.sidebar_project').toggle();
});
```

The problem here is that `$('.el.group_title a img')` just returns the a selection and when I do `$(this).nextUntil('.el.group_title', '.sidebar_project').toggle();`  I can't find the div.

So the idea is that it adds an img div, and when you click that img, the img changes and hides/shows the content `.sidebar_project` till the next img. I tried to change `$(this).nextUntil('.el.group_title a img'` but with no luck

On request this is the base html

```
<div class="el group_title">
  <a href="link_path">NAME</a>
</div>
<div data-project-id="195677" class="sidebar_project">..</div>
<div data-project-id="9844" class="sidebar_project">..</div>
<div class="el group_title">
  <a href="link_path">NAME 2</a>
</div>
<div data-project-id="195677" class="sidebar_project">..</div>
<div data-project-id="9844" class="sidebar_project">..</div>
```

Now when I add the img div

```
<div class="el group_title">
  <a href="link">
    <img alt="ACME org" src="link" width="20" height="20">org name</a>
</div>
....
```

Here is the jsFiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/6fdMc/

Comment: Can you post sample html which you get after appending?

Comment: Creating a jsfiddle would be an great idea, would be easier to see what the problem is.

Comment: Updated w the code I get

Comment: here is the jsfiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/6fdMc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell exactly what you're trying to do, but it sounds like part of the solution will be to `$( this ).closest( ".group_title" )`.  Are you trying to do something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/psZyE/3/)? This is the part that I changed in your code:

Original:

```
$(this).nextUntil('.el.group_title', '.sidebar_project').toggle();
```

New:

```
$( this ).closest( ".group_title" )

  .nextUntil( ".group_title", ".sidebar_project" ).toggle();
```

Comment: Works perfect that is what I wanted, why didnt worked my code ?

Comment: In your code `this` would be the `img` element. `nextUntil()` selects siblings of an element, and the `.sidebar_project` elements you wanted to select are not siblings of the `img` element. To select the elements you wanted, starting from the `img`, I used `closest()` to select the `.group_title` element that contains the `img`, then selected the `.sidebar_project` elements that are siblings of that `.group_title`.